# Cannot install docker pkg dependency in Go

Tags: go, docker

I'm trying to use the docker package in one of my Go applications. I'm importing the package as `import "github.com/dotcloud/docker"` in my script. But when trying to build the dependencies, that is, when I run `go get` in my project directory, it says:

```
foo.go:9:2: no buildable Go source files in /home/neville/gocode/src/github.com/dotcloud/docker
```

Here, my `GOPATH` is set to `/home/neville/gocode`, so when doing `go get`, the package should get downloaded to `/home/neville/gocode/pkg`, instead of `/home/neville/gocode/src`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`github.com/dotcloud/docker` isn't a Go package, and that's why there are no source files in that directory.

Import the package you want directly, like so for the registry package:

```
import "github.com/dotcloud/docker/registry"
```

Also, `go get` does download into `$GOPATH/src`. The installed object files go in `$GOPATH/pkg`.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. I want to use the docker pkg which can be used to spawn containers - essentially the go client library for docker. Can you point me to the correct package?

Comment: I have no idea, that's the repo for the entire docker runtime. What were you planning to do when you imported "docker"? I would start walking through the code from the docker cli main package, or look into another package that uses the remote API.

Comment: I'm trying to run this project locally.
https://github.com/hmarr/codecube/blob/master/server/runner.go#L9

Comment: I don't know. That project looks broken, so you'd have to fork and fix it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm gonna do I guess. Thanks.